# Python Adds An Extra CR At The End Of The Received Lines

Tags: java, python, sockets, client-server, carriage-return

A Java application sends an XML to a Python application. They are both on the same machine.
When I open the received file I can see extra lines (because of extra CRs). What could be the reason for this?

This is the receiver:

```
f = open('c:/python/python.xml', 'w')
while 1:
    print("xxx")        
    data = socket.recv(recv_frame)
    remain_byte = remain_byte - len(data)
    print(remain_byte)
    f.write(data)
    if (something):
        break
```

This is the sender:

```
    while ((bytesRead = file_inp.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output_local.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
```

This is the original file:

```
<root><CR><LF>
    <SONG><CR><LF>
        <ARTIST>Coldplay</ARTIST><CR><LF>
    </SONG><CR><LF>
</root><CR><LF>
```

This is the received:

```
<root><CR>
<CR><LF>
    <SONG><CR>
<CR><LF>
        <ARTIST>Coldplay</ARTIST><CR>
<CR><LF>
    </SONG><CR>
<CR><LF>
</root><CR>
<CR><LF>
```

Comment: What operating system are the applications running on? Is it windows?

Comment: Are you looking at the file "c:/python/python.xml"? On windows, some of the C libraries do carriage-return/line-feed processing to make UNIX files compatible with windows files. Unix only uses one character for line separation (\n), but Windows uses cr+lf. So it is just-about possible that two sets of processing (Java and Python) are expanding one line separator to two,

Comment: Yes, the file I'm checking is correct.

Comment: Change filemode from `'w'` to `'wb'`.

Comment: IIRC use "wb" when opening files for write, and that suppresses Python doing line separator expansion.

Comment: wb solved the issue!
great, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change filemode from `'w'` to `'wb'`, otherwise Python converts any newlines (`'\n'`) into the platform specific representation (`'\r\n'` for Windows).  Binary mode suppresses this conversion.